# (Python + Jira) How to process the Warnings in connection

Tags: python, jira

My connection code is:

```
try:
    jira_opts = {'server': jira_server}
    jira = JIRA(options=jira_opts, basic_auth=(jira_user, jira_password))
    return jira

except Exception, e:
    print "Unsuccessful attempt of connection to Jira"
    return None
```

If Jira server is not available (for example I forget to start the VPN client to my work network) then I received 10 times such warnings:

```
WARNING:root:HTTPSConnectionPool(host=jira_server', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /jira/rest/api/2/serverInfo (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x109a96bd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',)) while doing GET jira_server/jira/rest/api/2/serverInfo [{u'headers': {'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', u'Accept': u'application/json,*.*;q=0.9', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.14.2', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', u'X-Atlassian-Token': u'no-check', u'Cache-Control': u'no-cache', u'Content-Type': u'application/json'}, 'params': None}]
```

And just after 10 attempts of connection and 10 warnings in the terminal the exception is throwing and my code in the "exception" block started.

How I could change or switch off the attempts of connection?
I don't want to see the warnings. I just want to start exception block immediately after the first unsuccessful attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the documentation for the `JIRA` class. The constructor accepts the parameter `max_retries` to specify the number of retries for a connection attempt: https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#jira

Comment: Thank you so much! I was too blind when read the documentation.
"max_retries=0" - it is set up just one attempt for connection.